# Google Apps Script, function to return text as hyperlink

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script function `SearchFiles()` which returns the download urls depending on the keyword the user provides. It is something like this:

```
function SearchFiles(inputValueFromUser) {


  var searchFor ='title contains "' + inputValueFromUser + '"';
  var searchForAbsString = inputValueFromUser + '.pdf' ;

  //The Rest of the Code goes here

    if(file.getName() == searchForAbsString){
    downloadURL = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileId;
    arryOfUrls.push(downloadURL);
    };
  };

  Logger.log('arryOfUrls: ' + arryOfUrls);
  return arryOfUrls;//.toString(); //Send array of download urls back to client side JavaScript 
};
```

The function is returning `arryOfUrls` in plain text.

1) How can it be sent in hyperlink form?
2) Is it possible to open the URL automatically(start download immediately) as one clicks the respective button( on `Index.html`) to get the link?

Comment: No it can't be sent as a hyperlink directly (at least not as far I know). But you can have the HTML information embedded into the string (like "<a href="..."</a>"). This can be interpreted on the client side as a link.

Comment: I previously thought like this but din't try. Thanks a lot...it worked. Please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it can't be sent as a hyperlink directly (at least not as far I know). But you can have the HTML information embedded into the string (like `<a href=downloadUrl>...</a>"`). This can be interpreted on the client side as a link.